# This constantly results in "Error Cannot Find Symbol" in the terminal. Would very much appreciate if someone could tell me how to fix it

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

So, this is the sample code that we are supposed to use as reference for a formative assessment. I decided to run it in the terminal to see if it would work, and it always result in "Error Cannot Find Symbol". Would appreciate if someone could tell me how to fix it.

Here's the error message:

```
/Testing.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Person p1 = new Person();
        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Testing
/Testing.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Person p1 = new Person();
                        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Testing
/Testing.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Person p3 = new Person("Chris", 30);
        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Testing
/Testing.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Person p3 = new Person("Chris", 30);
                        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Testing
/Testing.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        Person p2;
        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Testing
/Testing.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        p2 = new Person();
                 ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Testing
6 errors
```

And here's the code:

```
public class Testing{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        //declare and instantiate;
        
        Person p1 = new Person();
        Person p3 = new Person("Chris", 30);

        //declare
        Person p2;
        //instantiate;
        p2 = new Person();

        //Assign values for p1 and p2
        /*
        p1.name="Lawrence";
        p2.name="Percy";

        p1.age=20;
        p2.age=-5;
        */
        p1.setName("Lawrence");
        p2.setName("Percy");
        


        p1.setAge(20);
        p2.setAge(-5);
        

        //Display values
        //System.out.println(p1.name + " at age " + p1.age);
        //System.out.println(p2.name + " at age " + p2.age);

        p1.showDetails();
        p2.showDetails();
        System.out.println(p3.getName() + " at age " + p3.getAge());



    }
}
```

Edit: People asked for the person class as well, so I'm putting it here:

```
public class Person{
    //variables
    private String name;
    private int age;


    //constructor
    public Person(){
        //nothing here...
    }

    public Person(String name, int age){
        setName(name);
        setAge(age);
    }

    //methods
    public void showDetails(){
        System.out.println(name + " at age " + age);
    }

    //Setters
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age){
        if(age>0)
            this.age=age;
        else
            this.age=0;

    }

    //Getters
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

}

class A{

}
```

Comment: Please include the full error message in your question.

Comment: and the command you are running

Comment: Hello, I included the error message.

Comment: Also include the `Person` class, and the command that you are running to compile your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I included the Person class as well

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run your code via the command `java Testing.java` you will need to have previously compiled any other class, i.e.:

```
$ javac Person.java
$ java Testing.java
```

This assumes that `Person` is in the default package, i.e. there is no `package` statement in `Person.java`.

If either `Person.java` or `Testing.java` have a `package ...;` statement, *remove* it.

Using the code which is in your question, this works:

```
tgdavies@DESKTOP-A4LJAJE:~/tmp$ ls
Person.java  Testing.java
tgdavies@DESKTOP-A4LJAJE:~/tmp$ javac Person.java
tgdavies@DESKTOP-A4LJAJE:~/tmp$ ls
A.class  Person.class  Person.java  Testing.java
tgdavies@DESKTOP-A4LJAJE:~/tmp$ java Testing.java
Lawrence at age 20
Percy at age 0
Chris at age 30
```

Notice the `.class` files which are produced by `javac`.

Comment: Hello, I tried doing this, and while the terminal did accept javac Person.java, the same issues still persisted. I also added in a package statement for both files.

Comment: If you have package statements the above won't work, I'll update the answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score -2):

Please import the package name of Person
or, declare two persons class